# Android sdk checkbox is missing in Android-Studio setup

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to install android studio + android SDK,

in this pic you see how it should be:

[image: Normal android setup]

and here is how I get it:

[image: adroid setuo missing sdk]

what should I do to get it? or any alternative how to install android sdk?

by the way, I tried to download the sdk (as .zip) and the sdk-manager is missing and I couldnt configure it in Android-Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have already installed Android SDK.

And don't worry, you can download Android SDK after install android studio.

Preference - (search)android sdk - Select version you want download - Press Apply button below.

[image: android sdk download]

Comment: I tried this but it shows nothing and says "Nothing to show".

Comment: @HareenLaks Did you installed "Android studio?" Does your internet connection is fine? Which screen can you see? (Can you find "SDK Platform section" from "Android SDK" menu?